# why celery worker spawn child process?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I used celery to do async long task in flask application, and specified concurrency as 8, but sometimes I can see more than 10 celery processes,I can't understand it, and then I use the pstree command show my process tree, and the result as below:
[pstree result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcLt8.png)

from this result, I found that the celery worker process spawn the child process, I can't found any explanation about this. can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you find out yet?